# D'où vient le e final de Cléopâtre en français ?

Tags: étymologie

Je lisais un texte d'histoire en français et j'ai été surpris de voir comment Κλεοπάτρα (Kleopátra) était écrit: Cléopâtre.

J'ai deux questions:

- pourquoi un accent sur le a (il y en a un en grec, mais le français les empruntent rarement je crois, et il n'y en a pas en latin),
- pourquoi une terminaison en -e plutôt qu'en -a comme dans toutes les autres langues (allemand, anglais, russe, etc) alors que des prénoms en -a sont assez communs en français.

Merci

Comment: Agathe, Anne, Cassandre, Diane, Eugénie, Hélène, Marie, Marine, Marthe, Sélène, Sophie...

Comment: Aphrodite, Olympe, Apolline, Josiane, Louise, Éléonore, Marianne, Romane, Garance, Coline, Gabrielle, Morgane, Mathilde, Bérénice, Thérèse, Adeline, Albertine, Alice, Armelle, Anémone, Béatrice, Bérénice, Iphigénie, Honorine, Sandrine...

Comment: Les accents en français ne sont pas d'« origine ». C'est une « invention » des imprimeurs de la Renaissance pour préciser la prononciation. L'accent circonflexe a probablement été mis pour indiquer qu'il fallait dire /ɑ/ et pas /a/. Ce n'est pas vraiment une question d'étymologie.

Comment: @None Je vois, mais en français moderne on prononce /a/ non? J'ai regardé quelques vidéos

Comment: On « devrait » prononcer /ɑ/ mais de nos jours en France peu de gens [quand ils parlent font la différence](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/522/358) entre les /pat/ de leur chien et les /pɑt/ qui sont dans leur assiette, c'est surtout [au Québec](https://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=4523) que la distinction est vivace.

Comment: @None merci pour les précisions

Comment: Je ne développe pas plus parce que je ne sais pas comment se prononçait le nom en grec et si l'ajout du circonflexe reflétait une prononciation établie au 16e siècle (donc qui venait de la prononciation du grec à cette époque) ou si c'est une décision arbitraire d'un imprimeur qui a décidé que ça devait se prononcer ainsi.

Comment: [The perennial](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/30830/where-did-frenchs-silent-ending-consonants-come-from/30831#30831)